# into_sub_account method not found

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I am trying to use PALLET_ID

```
const PALLET_ID: PalletId = PalletId(*b"ex/cfund");
 fn fund_account_id(index: FundIndex) -> T::AccountId {
            PALLET_ID.into_sub_account(index)
        }
```

But its giving error:

```
 method not found in `frame_support::PalletId`
```

Docs: [Link](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/struct.PalletId.html#method.into_sub_account)
All of the methods are inaccessible and giving error.

Version:
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
tag = 'monthly-2021-10'
version = '4.0.0-dev'

Answer (score 1):

This method is part of the trait `AccountIdConversion` which is implemented for the type `PalletId`.
So you need to have the trait in scope or call the method from the trait explicitly.

So like:

```rust
use sp_runtime::traits::AccountIdConversion;
const PALLET_ID: frame_support::PalletId = frame_support::PalletId(*b"ex/cfund");
fn fund_account_id(index: u32) -> u128 {
    PALLET_ID.into_sub_account(index)
}
```

or

```rust
const PALLET_ID: frame_support::PalletId = frame_support::PalletId(*b"ex/cfund");
fn fund_account_id(index: u32) -> u128 {
    sp_runtime::traits::AccountIdConversion::into_sub_account(&PALLET_ID, index)
}
```

Also in your example the type `FundIndex` needs to implement `Encode` to satisfy the trait implementation.